# Not able to update Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, windows, proxy, android-sdk-manager

Not able to update Android SDK Manager !!!

I am working behind the corporate proxy. Where Proxy setting is done using a script. I have checked the script and found that for my domain proxy setting made as "DIRECT".

Now in this condition, when I am trying to update SDK Manager, it is not able to update.

Getting error as below .

**

```
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused
```

**

But when I am trying to access https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml using browser, I am able to get the xml file.

It seems to me that I need to update Tools > Option > Proxy Setting in SDK Manager. but not able to find a way to set up the same in this case (When proxy setting set as DIRECT).

Please help me to set it up and resolve this issue.

Thanks
Ajoy Sinha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36913616/598802

Answer (score 0):

If you have issue with SSL you can try following.

[image]

Else try to replicate proxy settings of your browser into sdk mangers settings.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to do the ** "Force https://..." ** one ..but it didn't help. I have proxy setting into browser in "Automatic Configuration Script.." could you please let me know how to use the same setting in sdk manager setting .. I am stuck .. !!!

Comment: what is Configuration script?

Comment: This is proxy Configuration Script (called as PAC [Proxy Autometic Configuration] also) ..

Comment: there should be an ip address and port number. fill fields according to that.

Comment: Ahmed, that IP amd Port is not exposed ..it autometically use PAC file to get IP @ PORT at runtime. Hence I will not be able to get IP and Port ..I have to use PAC script .. need help