# Download API 21 on Android Studio : SDK Manager doesn't work

Tags: android, sdk

I develop a project on Android Studio.
This project is based on the API 21, but i have download a API 22.

So, i try to download the api 21 with SDK Manager, but i have some errors like this :

Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: Socket Permission denied: connect

already try :

- go to http://dl.google.com/android/repository/ and download sources-22_r01.zip, and dezip the .zip in D:\LOGICIEL\AndroidSDKLocation\sources\android-21
  Then, SDK Manager just found 'source for API 21', but i can't configure my emulator with SDK 21.
- Lauch in admin
- disable my firewall / Kaspersky
- in the past, i have a proxy settings. Maybe there are still some settings somewhere ? 
  Already chek in studio.exe.vmoptions and studio64.exe.vmoptions :nothing
- try to force https in option SDK
- set "no proxy" in android studio"

is there any log where i can find a error when i try to download/update in Android Studio ?

Thanks a lot for reading. I hape you will help me :)

Comment: i just found in C:\Users\rbt\.AndroidStudio1.2\config\options\proxy.settings.xml these lines :

<application>
  <component name="HttpConfigurable">
    <option name="PROXY_HOST" value="172.16.3.4" />
    <option name="PROXY_PORT" value="3128" />
  </component>
</application>

when i delete values or lines, Android Studio automatically rewrite in the file. Who know how or where i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem all the time and usually I use proxy to get access to Google repository for downloading sources and stuff. but if you want to install it manually you have to download related "System Images" ("sources" won't be enough for the emulator). it's normally called "ARM EABI v7a System Image" or "intel x86 Atom System Image" in SDK Manager.

In case you want to use intel-based emulator, you have to download and install HAXM too which can be downloaded from intel's website.

but it's far easier to use "Android SDK Manager" through a proxy than to do all this manually :)

Edit:
check this option in Android Studio for proxy issues :
File > Settings > HTTP Proxy (under "IDE Settings") > set it to "no proxy" if want to use your own IP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Http proxy is already at "no proxy". I have try to set "www.google.fr" in proxy, doesn't work too. (i have view this tips on a other topic.)
I don't understand what your tell about "System Image". My emulator work  well, but in api v22. i just need the "iso" of api21. A friend make a copie of his sdk's repertoire but now i have a message "Failed to load platform rendering library" when i open a layout..

Comment: when I said "I use proxy" I meant I use something like VPN. it always works for me. besides, have you tried downloading system images ?

Comment: I see, the sources are different from system images. even in SDK manager you have to download both to be able to use it in the emulator. see this for example. [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually)

Comment: it's a contournement situation, isn't it ? can we focus on the real problem : the connection of SDK Manager ? i think if i download the system image separatly, a other problem will be appear..

Comment: why don't you just reinstall Android Studio to get rid of the proxy malfunction ? if you know that Google hasn't limited your county's access to repository and your internet speed is good enough and stable you shouldn't have any problem with a new installation.

Comment: i have install on a VM with win7 : android Studio, SDK and TortoiseSVN, and c/c the repertory of SDK in my host'computer : working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a proxy issue with Android SDK Manager. You could try the following.

Search for the file:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\androidtool.cfg
```

Inside you have to add

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

In addition you have to fill in your proxy into the given settings:

```
http.proxyPort=<your Proxy Port>
http.proxyHost=<your Proxy URL / IP>
```

I have no clue why the latter is necessary. But after that your Android SDK Manager should be able to connect to the internet **and** the manager will ask for your credentials.

Answer (score -1):

To download SDK versions inside android studio,
go to Tools --> Android --> SDK manager then select the specific SDK versions you wish to downlaod.

Comment: Have you read my post ?
I will repeat : i have errors : Fetching http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect
Fetched Add-ons List successfully

Comment: Did you try the other versions to see if there is a problem with the specific SDK? Try restarting your PC, disabling your firewall,  or if you are really stuck and haven't started developing yet, uninstall android studio and re install it.

Comment: yes. but doesn't work. it seem a file config with a proxy settings doesn't change