# Android SDK Manager does not ask for proxy password

Tags: android, proxy, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I'm behind the company firewall and have to use proxy with authentication.

I have set up the right proxy url & port in Tools\Options in Android SDK Manager. Unfortunately, when I run Packages\Reload, I'm not asked for UserID\password for my proxy, so reload is failed with message "**Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect**"

One or two times it asked me about password (but I do not know why), and that times reload succeeded.

So, how to force SDK Manager to ask for proxy password?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36913616/598802

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you launch the manager with command line ?

```
pathtosdk\tools\android.bat update sdk --proxy-port yourport --proxyhost yourhost
```

Comment: Nop, the same thing:  

Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect  
 
Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: Socket Permission denied: connect

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install a local proxy like Squid that supports authentication and point sdkmanager to your local proxy.